# Installing CKAN error - cannot determine reason

Tags: centos, ckan, requirements.txt

Here is a list of packages I had to install for CKAN 2.7.0

```
python-setuptools-36.2.4-4.mga7.noarch.rpm
pgdg-redhat96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm

xml-commons git subversion mercurial postgresql96-server postgresql96-devel postgresql96 python-devel libxslt libxslt-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel python-virtualenv gcc gcc-c++ make java-1.6.0-openjdk redis tomcat tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps xalan-j2unzip policycoreutils-python mod_wsgi httpd tcl-devel redis
```

after installing these tools i was able to download the git successfully using

```
pip install --ignore-installed -e git+https://github.com/okfn/ckan.git@ckan-2.7.0#egg=ckan
```

I then added pgsql-9.6 to the path in order for ckan to recognize pg_config

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin
```

Now when I attempt to run the requirements.txt installation it fails with this error

```
ImportError: No module named pytz

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/usr/lib/ckan/default/build/pbr/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Aun2rR-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /usr/lib/ckan/default/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /usr/lib/ckan/default/build/pbr
Storing complete log in /usr/lib/ckan/.pip/pip.log
```

If anybody can explain what the error means and what I need to install/modify I would greatly appreciate it. Seems there is a package called pytz missing but I cannot find information about it.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the lines above the ImportError

Answer (score 0):

pytz must must installed inside the virtualenv and the pip-requirements-docs.txt must be run prior to running requirements.txt.